# ModelClientValidationRule conflict

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

I have installed vs 2011 developer preview side by side with vs 2010. Now when i run my asp.net mvc 3 project in vs 2010 I am getting the following error in my project where i am using ModelClientValidationRule.

> The type System.Web.Mvc.ModelClientValidationRule exists in both
>   c:\Program Files\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC
>   3\Assemblies\System.Web.Mvc.dll and c:\Program Files\Microsoft
>   ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v2.0\Assemblies\System.Web.WebPages.dll

Is this related to vs 2011 conlict with vs 2010 or something else

Answer (score 41, accepted):

please see the below release notes :

http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes

> **Installing ASP.NET MVC 4 Developer Preview breaks ASP.NET MVC 3 RTM
>   applications.**
>
> ASP.NET MVC 3 applications that were created with the RTM release (not
>   with the ASP.NET MVC 3 Tools Update release) require the following
>   changes in order to work side-by-side with ASP.NET MVC 4 Developer
>   Preview. Building the project without making these updates results in
>   compilation errors.
>
> http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes#_Toc303253815

Answer (score 72):

The accepted answer was "useful" but after installing MVC4 beta today, a few of my MVC 3 projects would not compile.  (ModelClientValidationRule conflict) The fix was:

Edit:

```
ProjectName.csproj
```

Change

```
<Reference Include="System.Web.WebPages"/>
```

To

```
<Reference Include="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL "/>
```

Comment: Or, more simply, just remove the reference to System.Web.WebPages.

Comment: I'm not sure that works off hand, I've moved onto to another contract job, so I cannot validate that it will work, if you experienced the problem, and got the results you desire then kudos.  thx

Comment: @Saulius  I wouldn't throw the baby out with the bathwater though.  System.Web.WebPages is sometimes needed.  Even Scott H. has it as part of his Bin Deploy  http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BINDeployingASPNETMVC3WithRazorToAWindowsServerWithoutMVCInstalled.aspx

Comment: @Tom Stickel didn't stumble at it till now. Just trying to be minimalistic. If my code breaks I vote up your answer :-)

Comment: Adding ", Version=1.0.0.0" is sufficient.

Comment: I just ran into this again about a year later!  I opened with VS 2010 a project I had downloaded and it gave the error, so I knew I planned on making changes to the application with VS 2012, so I opened with VS 2012 and it still gives the same error

Comment: @Quandary  Yes, I was finally able to validate that just adding Version=1.0.0.0 is sufficient.   Thus   <Reference Include="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0" />   Thanks

Comment: If you happen to be using the TagBuilder class then just removing the reference to System.Web.WebPages is *not* a solution as this is where this class got 'moved to' for the MVC 3 release -- it was apparently previously included in the MVC assembly.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you Christopher