# ASP.NET MVC 4 breaks ASP.NET MVC 3 projects

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

After installing the ASP.NET MVC 4 Developer Preview, I can no longer open MVC 3 projects, with the following error message:

```
The project type is not supported by this installation.
```

`<ProjectTypeGuids>` in my MVC 3 .csproj file looks right:

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{E53F8FEA-EAE0-44A6-8774-FFD645390401};{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

Is this a bug in the MVC 4 developer preview, or is something missing from my Visual Studio 2010 install? And how do I solve it? Should I rollback my MVC 4 install?

I have tried running `devenv /ResetSkipPkgs` and installed MVC 3 Tools Update, to no avail.

Comment: Go to Microsoft Web installer and install MVC4. Getting the MVC4 nugget is not enough.

Comment: It certainly wasn't the solution for the guys who followed the MVC4 installation guide and missinged installing MVC4 with Microsoft Web installer. So, it _wasn't_ the solution.

Answer (score 15):

"" If you want to update your projects to MVC4, and open them as such in the visual studio, then ""

The solution is to change the projectType guids from

```
{E53F8FEA-EAE0-44A6-8774-FFD645390401}
```

to

```
{E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47}
```

in the csproj file, after you install the mvc4 visual studio package.

Answer (score 3):

ASP.NET MVC 4 Developer Preview runs side by side with previous versions of ASP.NET MVC, however there are a few known issues to be aware of. The biggest one:

> Installing ASP.NET MVC 4 Developer Preview breaks ASP.NET MVC 3 RTM
>   applications. ASP.NET MVC 3 applications that were created with the
>   RTM release (not with the ASP.NET MVC 3 Tools Update release) require
>   the following changes in order to work side-by-side with ASP.NET MVC 4
>   Developer Preview. Building the project without making these updates
>   results in compilation errors.

You'll find the solutions [here](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes).

Comment: I updated the `System.Web.Mvc` & `System.Web.WebPages` references and added the `<appSettings>` keys, but it still won't open.

Comment: It's not that the project won't build - Visual Studio won't open it to begin with!

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for a different issue and stumbled across this question,  It is similar to a few I answered and figured I would post them here:

[ModelClientValidationRule conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510484/modelclientvalidationrule-conflict/9551774#9551774)

[Build Errors - 'System.Web.Mvc.ModelClientValidationRule' Conflicts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8512021/build-errors-system-web-mvc-modelclientvalidationrule-conflicts/9551791#9551791)

Answer (score 0):

Check the reference to System.Web.Mvc.dll file in your reference. Make sure its pointing to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 3\Assemblies\System.Web.Mvc.dll

If its pointing to the one under ASP.NET MVC 4 directory then open your project file in a notepad. Look for

```
<Reference Include="System.Web.Mvc">
  <Private>False</Private>
</Reference>
```

This should be changed to

```
<Reference Include="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
```