# Exception raise While Compiling my ASP.NET MVC3 Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Why this Exception is raise when i compile my ASP.NET MVC3 Application...

> The type 'System.Web.Mvc.ModelClientValidationRule' exists in both 'c:\Program Files\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v2.0\Assemblies\System.Web.WebPages.dll' and 'c:\Program Files\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 3\Assemblies\System.Web.Mvc.dll'

Comment: you didn't google enough !  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510484/modelclientvalidationrule-conflict