# Visual studio showing syntax errors in razor statements but works

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, visual-studio-2012, syntax-error

I've a project in MVC 3. It works perfectly and each time I build it, it succeeds. However, Visual Studio insist in showing compile errors in views in each razor syntax. For example:

> The name 'model' does not exist in the current context D:\ ... Detail.cshtml

That line is simple:

```
@model Namespace.DetailViewModel
```

I've already tried:

- Cleaning solution
- Cleaning solution and deleting `bin` and `obj` folders.
- Closing VS and reopening it (even with a reboot in the middle).

*Note:* I'm using Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the User Profile file?

Comment: No, I didn't think in that, but I finally found it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've solved it!

The project was created when the computer didn't have MVC 4 installed yet. After installing it, for some reason, it kept working (despite [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510484/modelclientvalidationrule-conflict)).

So what I did was make the changes that should be made in MVC 3 project after installing MVC 4: [see here](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes#_Toc303253815)

After that, it compiled and the errors disappeared, however there was an error with the versions of some libraries (`System.Web.WebPages`, `System.Web.WebPages.Razor`, and some others). That turned out to be because they had `Copy Local` set to `True`. After changing that everything started working great.

Answer (score 0):

Open your web.config file located inside of Views folder and add this section if it's missing:

```xml
<system.web.webPages.razor>
  <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
    <namespaces>
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    </namespaces>
  </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Comment: How does this fixes the problem?

Comment: It includes references used by @model in Views. If you start with a new empty ASP.NET MVC project, Visual Studio doesn't automatically include web.config file in Views folder. I thought that it might be similar problem.