# visual studio showing errors in typescript files but code works fine

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio

I am starting to learn angular2

and I happened to clone the [Angular 2 Quickstart](https://github.com/vigneshvdm/quickstart) from github

Now, what I noticed is that, some of the statements in typescript files are shown as errors in Visual Studio, but they actually work

[image]

I checked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14358789/visual-studio-showing-syntax-errors-in-razor-statements-but-works) which was resolved by installing MVC4 in the machine.

What should I install/do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience Visual Studio is a bit unstable with regards to this on-the-fly sync and compile. What helped me is just a simple restarting of Visual Studio (if all other stuff is in order).

If that does not help, it's better to update TypeScript to latest version. I do it first thing in Visual Studio. You cannot do it directly from extension tab unfortunately, so you need to download it from [MS site](http://microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593).

P.S. The Url might change later of course if new versions are released.

Comment: But you are saying that you have proper .js files in there and if you do a change it will recompile and change the .js file as well?

Comment: Another thing - did you try to update typescript version? I do it first thing in Visual Studio. You cannot do it directly from extension tab unfortunately, so you need to download it from MS site (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593)

Comment: it worked! pls add it to the answer :) 
upvoted and accepted