# Error on cshtml but build and deploy

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, razor

I just installed a fresh VS2013 on new machine (from Win7 to Win10), and I get all my cshtml views that are giving me errors.

I tried to

- Reset my VS settings by using console devenv /resetsettings
- Reset my settings by using Tools menu > Import and Export Settings > Reset all settings > Next > "No, just reset settings, overwriting all current settings" > Next > Finish.
- remove the suo
- repair my VS2013 install
- clean all projects & build
- Options>Text Editor > All languages > uncheck all "Statement completion", save, close, open and check them all

Next step is:

- banging my head against the wall (haha)

It looks like it's a VS issue because when I take another web-project (a branch of this project) in TFS that run on another PC I get errors too.

It builds and it runs in localhost, but Razor give me error on Viewbag, Model, Html.LabelFor, etc.

When I clean project, no mistake but when I build it, I get all those "false" errors highlighted only in cshtml's...

Thanks to help

[image: visual studio cshtml issue]

**EDIT**
I've MVC installed and copy local @ true
[image: MVC DLL]

Comment: I’m confused. What exactly is your problem? That you had to update the version of a referenced assembly because you are running this on an updated machine that does not have the old versions..?

Comment: @poke clarified. I've clarified question... I said that the only change that I've done on the code since I've switched my PC was changing assembly version on config file (from assembly Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common v9 to 11). Just as info.

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14358789/visual-studio-showing-syntax-errors-in-razor-statements-but-works

Comment: @Artiom Good try, thank you. I've the good version of MVC installed on this computer and copy local at true (I've edited the question to add prtscr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution... Update Visual studio 2013 to 2013 update 5!